# Read More tag deleting content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I try to add the `<!--more-->` tag to my post content and update, it deletes all of my post apart from the content before the `<!--more-->` tag.

Why is this happening?

Comment: On the front-end or in the `wp-admin`?

Comment: on the wp-admin. It works fine if the <!--more--> tag is ommitted.

Comment: On a closer look, I realized that it's not the <!--more--> tag but the update button that is deleting part of the content. Whenever I open a post for editing and click on the update to reflect the changes, I end up losing a section of the post.

Comment: When did this start? after the 3.5 update? after installing a plugin?

Comment: Yes, after  installing the latest version 3.5. So it seems to be something with the jQuery / javascript interfering with the default wordpress post editor.

Answer (score 0):

I advise replacing the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folder with new one, from the zip found [here](http://wordpress.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was something to do with the default wordpress editor. I installed the [ck editor plugin for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/)

and it worked fine.